# Unable to upgrade firmware on Vidonn X6 bracelet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I bought myself a Vidonn X6 sports band, and am having issues upgrading the firmware.

The new version released last week of the app on the Android adds support for the X6, and is offering a newer firmware version for my sports band. When I try to install it, the band's face shows up 'Up' arrow (taking on an upgrade), and stays for approximately one minute, while the phone stays on the 'Upgrading' screen in the app.

After a minute, the arrow disappears off the band, and the Bluetooth settings screen comes on. I have tried:

- waiting,
- backing out to the app, and
- disabling the Wifi so Vidonn asks to turn it on.

None of these seem to finish the upgrade, and in all instances, I have to pair the sports band back to my phone. The battery was charged up to 100%, so I know it's not a power issue.

What more can I try to get the newer firmware installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to update, after no help from their tech support.

Start the upgrade, and wait for the Bluetooth settings screen to come up. I scanned for devices, and got a new gibberish device to connect to, as shown below. It now successfully reads as an x6 bracelet, but was gibberish the first time I saw it.

[image]

<sub>(Click on the image to see enlarged view.)</sub>

I was then able to successfully upgrade the firmware. The upgrade bar turned green, and it copied over, using my only Android device, a OnePlus One.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue on my OnePlus, unable to upgrade firmware, my smartband had some issues (screen not working). After long search, found it : uninstall vidonn2.0 app , download vidonn tool.apk and firmware https://goo.gl/BZYGsQ (read the text file) then install it, reboot phone, launch Vidonn tool then flash firmware. You can also try to flash the firmware in the Vidonn2.0 directory on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please install and open the upgrade tool.
2. Search X6 and click to connect with X6.
3. after connected successfully and display "Unknown service 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" .Click "Reset(upgrade)"
4. X6 will display arrow icon.
5. With arrow icon on smart band go Back to search page, it will display "DfuTarg".
6. Click"DfuTarg" and connect it.
7. Connected and it will display "Unknown service 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", then Click "Select File" and choose the file. then it wil upgrade automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have THREE of these bracelets to be used as gift and yes, they are very flaky in the software.Mind you, the hardware bits are simple and (I think) pretty robust if the water-proofing works properly. Just DO NOT swim with this on!.

As to firmware upgrade. I have 3 phones and only ONE will upgrade the firmware. I found that the latest Android Kitkat V4.4.4 works in my case as it is a new phone I got from a warranty claim. The software upgrade goes into the screen, then the red letters on the bottom of the screen turns green and the big circle starts the percent count from 1% to 100% and device resets and repairs with the phone. So, it is a Bluetooth or software issue relating to bluetooth stack in the PHONE itself rather than the device. Since Bluetooth 4.0 is new, the profile part in the phone can be tricky and there is nothing you can do except to upgrade the software on the phone itself and try again.

My Lenovo phone upgraded to V4.4.2 also CANNOT upgrade the firmware of the X6 but works well with it. The ANdroid app is also poor quality and reliablity of sync is also about 80%. Not good but passable.

Answer (score 0):

Ive now done 2 upgrades and figured it out.

After you try to upgrade the first time, the Vidonn phone app will hang.  You have to kill the app in the task manager.  Important:  Then go into bluetooth settings and unpair the bracelet from the phone.

Then relaunch the phone app and start the upgrade process again,  This time you will see the circle move and do the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a firmware upgrade of very old Vidonn X6 wristband by following [this answer(this thread)](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/117578/330279). I am using a Vidonn App and VidonnTools App from the website linked on that answer. My X6 now has a v2.9.0.0 release. Vidonn Android App version is v3.2.4.

Before upgrade Vidonn Android app told X6 was a version v2.7.0.6. Link above answer had a firmware file but it was v2.6.2.1. German website lists firmware history and latest one is v2.9.0.0. I could not find a binary in the same german website but they link to a russian(?) website with all firmwares available.

http://www.vidonn.com/en/faq.html
[https://vidonnx6.tumblr.com/post/126413649799/firmwareupdate-durchführen](https://vidonnx6.tumblr.com/post/126413649799/firmwareupdate-durchf%C3%BChren)
https://yadi.sk/d/jKHO8XrthJ63n/Firmware%20X6